# Erro nos projetos ao atualizar o Visual Studio 2017 para a versão 15.6.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Após atualizar a versão do Visual Studio para o update [15.6.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) todos os meus projetos (`C#`) passaram a mostrar estes erros:

```
The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task could not be initialized with its input parameters

The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task could not be initialized with its input parameters      

The "FindDependenciesOfExternallyResolvedReferences" parameter is not supported by the "ResolveAssemblyReference" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property          

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them
```

Já tentei reinstalar, reparar e nada resolveu.

No [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/208668/the-finddependenciesofexternallyresolvedreferences.html) possui um tópico aberto, mas sem respostas até o momento.

Comment: A pergunta é uma tentativa de catalogar este erro e apresentar sua solução em português. Uma ótima forma de ajudar a comunidade. Alguém pode me explicar por que ela foi negativada?

Comment: Programadores de sublime se sentiram ofendidos @LINQ ahahahah

Answer (score 5):

Conforme [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156397/4843158), o problema foi que a atualização corrompeu o arquivo `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`. Basta atualizar este arquivo que o problema é sanado.

Diretório padrão VS Enterprise:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017>EnterpriseWMSBuild\15.0\bin>Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
```

Diretório padrão VS Community:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

Caso alguém precise, até a MS corrigir, o arquivo pode ser baixado [neste link.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LB2iLi1_1kIeqcDLcatXjkfTep8d4y8-/view?usp=sharing)